# uploading images to S3 using SDK skipping cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timeout, amazon-cloudfront, uploading

**Setup:**

We are running a E-commerce website consists of Cloudfront-->ALB-->EC2. we are serving the images from S3 via cloudfront behaviour.

**Issue:**

Our admin URL is like example.com/admin. We are uploading product images via admin panel as a zip file that goes via cloudfront.Each zip file size around 100MB-150MB consists of around 100 images. While uploading the zip file we are facing 502 gateway error from cloudfront since it took more than 30sec, which is default time out value for cloudfront.

**Expected solution:**

1. Is there a way we can skip the cloudfront for only uploading images?
2. Is there any alternate way increasing timeout value for cloudfront??

**Note:** Any recommended solutions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is a CDN service to help you speed up your services by caching your static files in edge location. So it won't help you in uploading side

In my opinion, for the uploading images feature, you should use the AWS SDK to connect directly with S3.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion..Any reference link i could follow??

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: This is an example of NodeJS. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helps you
https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-using-nodejs

Comment: Thanks again..we are using nodejs only..I believe we can adjust timeout value in SDK rite??

Comment: This is like your 1 solution "Is there a way we can skip the cloudfront for only uploading images?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files directly to s3 from the client, I can highly suggest using s3 presigned URLs.

You create an endpoint in your API to create the presigned URL for a certain object (myUpload.zip), pass it back to the client and use that URL to do the upload. It's safe, and you won't have to  expose any credentials for uploading. Make sure to set the expiration time to a reasonable time (one hour).

More on presigned URLs's here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/